# parameters not recognized following decimal values

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack recognizes the parameter (RADIUS in my case) if the preceding parameters (latitude and longitude) does NOT have a decimal in the URL. Once I place the decimal in the latitude or longitude I get a "Handler for Request not found". Below are my code and error

here is the Location class

```
public class Location
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Latitude", Order = 5)]
    public double? LATITUDE { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Longitude", Order = 6)]
    public double? LONGITUDE { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Radius", Order = 7)]
    public double? RADIUS { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my AppHost path definitions

```
Routes.Add<Location>("/Locate/geo/{LATITUDE}/{LONGITUDE}", "GET");
Routes.Add<Location>("/Locate/geo/{LATITUDE}/{LONGITUDE}/rad/{RADIUS}", "GET");
Routes.Add<Location>("/Locate/rad/{RADIUS}/geo/{LATITUDE}/{LONGITUDE}", "GET");
```

Below are my results

works

```
http://localhost:2222/api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911?format=xml
http://localhost:2222/api/Locate/rad/20/geo/30.1783/-96.3911?format=xml
```

Does not work

```
http://localhost:2222/api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911/rad/20?format=xml
```

- I get the following error

Handler for Request not found:

Request.ApplicationPath: /

Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911

Request.FilePath: /api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911

Request.HttpMethod: GET

Request.MapPath('~'): C:\Webservices\

Request.Path: /api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911/rad/20

Request.PathInfo: /rad/20

Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /rad/20

Request.PhysicalPath: C:\Webservices\api\Locate\geo\30.1783-96.3911

Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: C:\Webservices\

Request.QueryString: format=xml

Request.RawUrl: /api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911/rad/20?format=xml

Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://localhost:2222/api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911
/rad/20?format=xml

Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911/rad/20

Request.Url.Fragment:

Request.Url.Host: localhost

Request.Url.LocalPath: /api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911/rad/20

Request.Url.Port: 2222

Request.Url.Query: ?format=xml

Request.Url.Scheme: http

Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]

App.IsIntegratedPipeline: False

App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\Webservices

App.DefaultHandler: DefaultHttpHandler

App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/api/Locate/geo/30.1783/-96.3911|C:\Webservices\api\Locate\geo\30.1783-96.3911

If the decimal is the issue wonder how does the first URL with both Lat & Long works with decimals in place. Pls correct me if any of the AppHost path is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872793/85785):

There are 2 component separators in ServiceStack's Routes: `.`  and `/`, here's an example showing [different Route path ServiceStack supports](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests/RestPathTests.cs#L99).

You can try url encoding the `.` so its `%2E` otherwise just add the action as a querystring parameter, e.g: `/path/to/me%40example.com?action=action`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will try the alternates.