# Period in ServiceStack Routes works in IIS6.0 but not in Dev server?

Tags: iis, routes, servicestack

I am using service stack and I need to have periods included in my routing for example to indicate a version number, eg
/Model/v1.0/Save

When I deploy the service onto IIS6 it works perfectly, however when i run it locally through Visual Studio I get an error of 
Request handler not found. 
If I remove the period then it works!!

I have looked through all the questions and there was a similiar one, 
[ServiceStack Handler Not Found When Periods Present in Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866145/servicestack-handler-not-found-when-periods-present-in-path)
BUT the answer implies that it cant be done and I have seen it working. Secondly in the link referenced in the answer the Service Stack rest tests seem to show that a Version number with a period is a valid route??
See here
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests/RestPathTests.cs#L210

Please can someone give me some guidance on this one!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just answered [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698006/servicestack-period-in-route-path-causes-404-error), and i think the same should apply in this case: Visual Studio Development Server (Cassini) does incorrect routing for dots.

> If you create a file system Web site in Visual Studio 2010 and the Web site is in a folder that contains a dot (.) in the folder name, URL routing will not work reliably. An HTTP 404 error is returned from some virtual paths. This occurs because Visual Studio 2010 launches the Visual Studio Development Server (Cassini) using an incorrect path for the root virtual directory.

There are 3 workarounds, and only the "use IIS instead of Cassini" workaround seems to work for ServiceStack.

The problem will go away if you edit your project Web properties and check "Use IIS Express" instead of "Visual Studio Development Server".

The cases to use IIS Express are [explained in the announcement, and there is a download link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx).